# Armatures breaking apart mesh on pose?

Tags: mesh, armature, rigify

I currently have a mesh that I made of individual cubes that I have joined into the components I want to add motion to (the arm/sword should move as a single unit)
[image]

I Have added armatures and set the limbs parent to the center bone with the "keep offset" setting. I selected all the components of my character and set the armature deform to automatic weights.

I Just want to be able to freely rotate the limbs / head about the axis at the base of each bone, but I can't seem to get that to happen as the mesh just breaks apart, picking seemingly arbitrary pieces to drag with it (which I dont quite understand, since I have joined the cubes together into the components I do want to move)

[image]

[image: Another breaking example]

Anyone have any tips for how to get this set up properly?

Comment: it looks like your head mesh is cut in half?

Comment: The head is 1 piece, composed of a bunch of individual cubes but they're all joined together

Comment: oh ok so it looks like the right part is not correctly assigned to the head bone, you need to select them all in Edit mode, go in the Object Data panel > Vertex Groups, select the head vertex group, and assign

Comment: Hmm currently all the bones show up in the vertex groups for the head, when I remove all of them except for the head bone i have the same break apart issue

Comment: I think its mostly an issue with it regarding my mesh as individual cubes instead of the joined together components ive made with them

Comment: individual cubes may be not a good idea but it should not be the problem here, but maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/d1f761d9c7a2448ca1125ba5d0d52931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cubes are assigned to some vertex groups that they should not be part of, so select all the head cubes, go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups* list, and Remove from All Groups:

[image]

Then assign them to the group that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control them (*Bone.001*):

[image]

It works:

[image]

Comment: AHHHH I LOVE YOU